# how to rank gene using information gain?

Tags: database, statistics, bioinformatics

how gene ranking is done for microarray data using information gain and chi-square statistics ?? Please illustrate with a simple example..

Comment: did you search in pubmed ? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right forum for this question; you'll see plenty of programmers here, but this is *very* specific.

Comment: This should be closed as not programming related.  It's **much** more a question about a problem domain than about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the open source machine learning software [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). Load your dataset and go to "Select attribute" tab. Use the following attributes evaluators:

**ChiSquaredAttributeEval** : Evaluates the worth of an attribute by computing the value of the chi-squared statistic with respect to the class.

**InfoGainAttributeEval** : Evaluates the worth of an attribute by measuring the information gain with respect to the class.

..using **Ranker** in the "Search Method" . That way the attributes are ranked by their individual evaluations

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your question, but a very successful package for analyzing microarray data can be found here:

[BioConductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/)

This is a software project that has a variety of different modules for reading data from microarrays and performing statistical analysis. This is very useful, because the file formats for microarray data are constantly changing as the technology develops, and the algorithms for analyzing microarray data have advanced significantly as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `InfoGainAttributeEval`  for calculating Information gain
and for more information [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063206/information-gain-calculation-for-a-text-file)