# Information Gain Calculation for a text file?

Tags: java, data-mining, information-retrieval, text-mining

I'm working on **"text categorization using Information gain,PCA and Genetic Algorithm"** But after performing **Preprocessing**(Stemming, stopword removal, TFIDF) on the document m confused how to move ahead for information gain part.

my **out file** contain **word** and there **TFIDF** value.

like
**WORD - TFIDF VALUE**

together(word) - 0.235(tfidf value)

come(word) - 0.2548(tfidf value)

when using weka for information gain ("**InfoGainAttributeEval.java**") it require **.arff** file format as input.

Is there any to convert **text** file into **.arff** format.
or any other way to preform Information gain other than weka?

Is there any other open source for Calculating information gain for document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.
In this we have to generate **arff** file.

In .arff file

**@RELATION section** will contain all words present in your whole document after **preprocessing** .Each word will be of type **real** because **tfidf value** is a real value.

**@data section** will contain their **tfidf** value calculated during **preprocessing**.
for example first will contain **tfidf value** all words present in first document an at last  colunm the document categary.

```
@RELATION filename
@ATTRIBUTE word1 real
@ATTRIBUTE word2 real
@ATTRIBUTE word3 real
.
.
.
.so on
@ATTRIBUTE class {cacm,cisi,cran,med}

@data
0.5545479562,0.27,0.554544479562,0.4479562,cacm
0.5545479562,0.27,0.554544479562,0.4479562,cacm
0.55454479562,0.1619617,0.579562,0.5542,cisi
0.5545479562,0.27,0.554544479562,0.4479562,cisi
0.0,0.2396113617,0.44479562,0.2,cran
0.5545479562,0.27,0.554544479562,0.4479562,carn
0.5545177444479562,0.26196113617,0.0,0.0,med
0.5545479562,0.27,0.554544479562,0.4479562,med
```

after you generate this file you can give this file as input to `InfoGainAttributeEval.java`. and this working for me.

Comment: if any problem in understanding above process just add comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I converted the .dat file to a .xlsx file (Excel) and this solved the problem.